# CAKeyframeAnimation Keypath Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation, cakeyframeanimation

I am trying to animate the `transform` property of a view. Here is my code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *shakeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
NSArray *transformValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((3*M_PI)/8)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-((3*M_PI)/8))],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((3*M_PI)/8)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-((3*M_PI)/8))],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((3*M_PI)/8)],
                        [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-((3*M_PI)/8))],
                        nil];

[shakeAnimation setValues:transformValues];

NSArray *times = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.16f],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.33f],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.49f],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.66f],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.82f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];

[shakeAnimation setKeyTimes:times];

NSArray *timingFunctions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut], 
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut],
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut], 
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut], 
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut], 
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut], 
nil];

[shakeAnimation setTimingFunctions:timingFunctions];

shakeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
shakeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
shakeAnimation.duration = 1.0f;

[self.someView.layer addAnimation:shakeAnimation forKey:@"anim"];
```

For some reason, I get an error whenever I set the parameter of the method `animationWithKeyPath:` to "transform". I have tried for half an hour to debug this, but can't find the error. I initially though that I was performing an animation not allowed on a UIView's transform property, but I know that I can do something like this:

```
aView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of a layer's `transform` property is a `CATransform3D`, not a `CGAffineTransform`.

Also, you might find it simpler to animate the `transform.rotation.z` key path.  The value is just a `CGFloat`, so you don't have to create a transform matrix at all.

[“Modifying a Transform Using Key Paths” in *Core Animation Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW17)
[“Key Path Support for Structure Fields” in *Core Animation Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/KVCAdditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005299-SW6)

Comment: You're right! I was thinking about a view's `transform` property. Thanks so much. Also, the `CGFloat` value that the `transform.rotation.z` key path takes represents what? The angle (if so radians or degrees)?

Comment: Nevermind. I checked out your link. It's the rotation angle in radians.